# How do you use ellipses in conjunction with semicolons in MLA quoting?

Tags: quotations, semicolons, mla

Here is a line of text from Willa Cather’s *My Ántonia*.

> There was only—spring itself; the throb of it, the light restlessness...

I wish to end the quote at the semicolon. Eg:

> "There was only—spring itself;..." Jim says (Ln 5).

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you need the semicolon? Why not stop at the *f*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that example, the semicolon exists only to separate two clauses.  Since you're leaving out the rest of the sentence, there is nothing to separate.  It serves no purpose and can safely be omitted.

> "There was only—spring itself..." Jim says (Ln 5).